# Maintaining Many to Many relation with checkboxes (e.g. checkboxes for each category a post can be in)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-datamapper

We have a table with Categories containing unique categories. And our posts should link to any of these categories. I tried to add checkboxes for selecting the categories in the following manner:

1. Add the checkboxes containing the categories in a field called "post[categoriesss][]", containing as value the `:id` of the category.
2. Update the `new` and `update` method to take these these ids and collect the associated Categories with them, and then add each category to the categories attribute through the `<<` operator as stated in the [documentation](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html).

We added the code to `new` and `update` to be sure not to have to do this in multiple controllers.

However we get the following error:

> undefined property or relationship '<<' on Category

What are we doing wrong here? Is there another method to achieve our goal? Our code is below.

```ruby
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource  

  property :id,               Serial

  has n, :categories, :through => Resource

  def self.new(hash={})


    if hash.key? :categoriesss
      hash[:categoriesss].each do |category|
        categories << Category.get(category)
      end
      hash.delete! :categoriesss
    end    

    super hash
  end

end

class Category
  include DataMapper::Resource  

  property :id,       Serial
  property :name,     String,   :required => true

  has n, :rekenservices, :through => Resource
end
```

```html
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="post[categoriesss][]" value="<%= category.id %>" />
      <%= category.name %>
    </label>
  <% end %>
```

**UPDATE**:
I now changed the names for the checkbox back to `categories` and updated the `new` and `update` methods to this:

```ruby
  def self.new(hash={})
      if hash.key? :categories
        hash[:categories].map! {|id| Category.get id}
      end    
      super hash
  end

  def update(hash={})
    if hash.key? :categories
      hash[:categories].map! {|id| Category.get id}
    end    
    super hash
  end
```

Adding categories the first time works. When updating checking an extra category works great as well. Unchecking a category however yields an error message:

> columns category_id, post_id are not unique

Comment: To whom it may concern: The problems mentioned here are fixed when defining our own relationship model `CategoryPost` and by updating the `has n` properties accordingly. I will leave this question open for a while in case someone comes along with an answer with why it won't work when using `Resource`.